# Only getting first letter of only first column in database

Tags: php, mysql

While retrieving content from database, only first letter from first column is shown like

```
  SELECT LEFT(`name`, 1) AS first_letter FROM register
```

I want to retrieve more than one column from database. Is there anyway..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just list them comma seperated in your select statement

```
SELECT LEFT(`name`, 1) AS first_letter_name,
       LEFT(`second_col`, 1) AS first_col2,
       LEFT(third_col, 1) AS first_letter_col3,
FROM register
```

Comment: Thank u for your reply..:-)....we got other two columns, but we want first letter of other two columns...@ juergen d

Comment: I noticed that you did not use a feature of Stack Overflow yet. You can mark answers to your question as correct by clicking the checkmark under the answer score. Maybe you like to revisit your past questions and see if some of these answers are worth accepting.

Comment: sorry dude...i dont knw that feature.....im new to stack overflow....i tried to vote up...but it requires more than 15 reputation......anyway....u r great....:-)...@juergen d